# How to pass base64 string to a fetch API body payload?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to pass a base64 string to an API so it can be stored. I am using the library: https://github.com/malsapp/react-native-photo-upload

```
<PhotoUpload
     onPhotoSelect={avatar => {
       if (avatar) {
    console.log('Image base64 string: ', avatar)
       }
 }}  >
<Image style={{width: 90, height: 90, marginLeft: 10, marginTop: 10, resize: 'cover'}} source = {{uri: 'https://api.helloworld.com/assets/member.png'}}></Image>
```

Using this code, how would I pass avatar to a payload? I want to store the base64 string so I can store this in the API which the code is located below:

```
signup = () => {          
fetch('https://helloworld.app.com/api/signup.json', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
body: JSON.stringify({
    "name": this.state.name,
    "password": this.state.password,
    "email": this.state.email,
    "avatar": this.state.avatar,
  })
})
.then((response) => response.json())
.then ((res) => {
```

How can I approach this? I've tried creating a state/prop for avatar but that threw errors.

Answer (score 0):

There is javascript function window.btoa() which encodes data to Base64 string :

```
signup = () => {          
    fetch('https://helloworld.app.com/api/signup.json', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
       'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        "name": this.state.name,
        "password": this.state.password,
        "email": this.state.email,
        "avatar": window.btoa(this.state.avatar),
  })
})
.then((response) => response.json())
.then ((res) => {
```

Comment: When I do that it doesn't seem to pick up on the reference. It keeps assigning the default image the API contains to the user.

Comment: @Ferrarella Did you ever resolve this? I'm trying the same with Axios, first encoding the target file in base64 using `fileReader.readAsDataURL()` but the resulting value is null in the API post call. Appreciate any insight you may have gained.