# How to send Base64 code to webservice webservice?

Tags: react-native

*I try to send my base64 code to my webservice :*

**this is my base64 :**

[image]

**I send like this :**

```
 let collection= {};
    collection.base64 = this.state.data;

    fetch('url',  {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: new Headers({
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json', // <-- Specifying the Content-Type
      }),
      body: JSON.stringify({'JsonWithImage': collection.base64 }), // data can be `string` or {object}!
    })
```

*However, as you see it gives error message which is in image. I think because of size of image but I am not sure. Any idea about this ?*

Comment: Why you give this question '-' ? can u please explain ? is it too easy or bad question ?  if it is, give me reason !!!

Answer (score 0):

Via [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51797166/how-to-pass-base64-string-to-a-fetch-api-body-payload) there is a javascript function window.btoa() which encodes data to Base64 string which may work for you.

```
let collection= {};
collection.base64 = this.state.data;

fetch('url',  {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: new Headers({
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json', // <-- Specifying the Content-Type
  }),
  body: JSON.stringify({'JsonWithImage': window.btoa(collection.base64) }), // data can be `string` or {object}!
})
```

Comment: It is hard to know what is causing the issue, it could be completely server side and not a problem with the client. Do you have some way to monitor or get a more detailed reply from the service?

Comment: if I send string not like long as base64,, it save to database. however it gives error when I send base64